# Tomcat error eclipse juno

Tags: tomcat, servlets

Hi i was using eclips juno with tomcat 7... firstly all works fine. but after two days i got error that tomcat unable to start... I tried to restart eclips, delete server and add again, restart computer, increase timeout, configured tomcat plugin(found in an article). All in vain... Pls help me. The error message...

```
 Feb 5, 2013 8:39:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
 INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in
 production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Java\jre6\bin;C:
\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Java/jre6/bin/client;C: 
/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32
\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Panda 
Security\Panda Internet Security 2012;C:\Program Files\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba 
Stack\sys\;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin;E:
\eclipse-jee-juno-win32\eclipse;;.

Feb 5, 2013 8:39:24 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin

WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property

'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:BlackBookServlets' did not find a matching 
property.

Feb 5, 2013 8:39:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 5, 2013 8:39:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 5, 2013 8:39:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 400 ms
Feb 5, 2013 8:39:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 5, 2013 8:39:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
Feb 5, 2013 8:39:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:   
Failed to start component   
 [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BlackBookServlets]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component   
 [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BlackBookServlets]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 7 more
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern>  
 BlackBookServlets/UploadServlets in servlet mapping
at   
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3223)
at 
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3198)
at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1366)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1353)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
at 
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
 Feb 5, 2013 8:39:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
 SEVERE: A child container failed during start
  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:  
 Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
  [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during 
 start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
   Feb 5, 2013 8:39:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
  SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component   
 [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
 [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
  [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during 
  start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more
 Feb 5, 2013 8:39:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
 INFO: Server startup in 492 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling tomcat server. I think some settings got changed.

Also check whether your firewall is not blocking it.